# How to open user's URL-link (any link) from UITextField in SFSafariViewController with interval? / Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, sfsafariviewcontroller

---

Hello everyone!) Need some help!)

How can I open any URL-link from UITextField in SFSafariViewController with interval?

---

**This is what I meant when I said "any link"…**

> **First:** I means that if we have full link with **https://**.., like: **https://www.google.com/**
> In this case, the link should be opened automatically with interval like 3 seconds.

> **Second:** If we have link with without **https://**.., like: **[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**
> In this case - **https://** must be added automatically, then the link should be opened automatically with interval like 3 seconds.

> **And the third:** If we have only **stackoverflow.com** without **https://www**.., Then - **https://www** must be added automatically and then the link should be opened automatically with interval like 3 seconds.

---

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SafariServices

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    if let urlString = linkTextField.text {
        let url: URL?
        if urlString.hasPrefix("http://") {
            url = URL(string: urlString)
        } else {
            url = URL(string: "http://" + urlString)
        }
        if let url = url {
            let sfViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            self.present(sfViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print ("Your link was opened in SFSafariViewController")
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

---

**Do you have any ideas how to implement this?) Thanks for every answer!)**

---

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. See also [ask].

Comment: `shouldChangeCharacters` will be called every time the user enters something. Consider executing this logic on a button press or on return.

Comment: @koen Hi!) This is one question regarding the use of a UITextField and SFSafariViewController.) I just explained what should function do when we put our link in UITextField.) And that's all..)

Comment: @Timmy Hi!) I understand, thats why I want to implement it with an interval. Also we can add text field clearing after exiting SFSafariViewController and "placeholder" like: "Type the next link..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I don't think it'll be a good user interface(for instance the user is thinking while typing & takes too long), use `DispatchQueue.main.asynAfter`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asynAfter(deadline: .now() numberOfSeconds) {
    let sfViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    self.present(sfViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Great, I will check it!) I'm still learning Swift.) This is just for personal development, not for a commercial project!) I just haven't found any solution yet, that's why I decide to discuss it.) Thanks a lot and have a nice day!)

Comment: If my answer was helpful consider pressing the checkmark above to mark the answer as accepted. have a great day!